# error in batch sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

For list1, select 'ok' will be run even select 1/0 generate an error. for list 2 select 'ok' will not be run since update fail. Both list generate error of level 16 but why there are such difference?

```
--1
select 1/0  
select 'ok'

--2
create table #t (a int)
insert into #t values(1)

update #t set b = 99
select 'ok'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update #t set b = 99` is a compile time error.

The batch is compiled and as `#t` does not exist that statement is subject to a deferred compile. It is impossible to even generate a plan for this statement to update a non existent column so there is a compile error on that statement.

Runtime compile errors abort the scope.

It is not always intuitive what effect a runtime error will have (abort the statement, scope, batch or connection). See [What Happens when an Error Occurs?](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#whathappens) for some examples.

Comment: for list2 there is no compile error either. both lists generate error when running the codes. But the link in the reply seems nice. I am reading it. Cheers.

Comment: @thotwielder - The error **is** a compile time error. You can tell that by creating the temporary table then trying to generate an estimated execution plan for the statement update `#t set b = 99`. I presume you missed what I wrote about **deferred** compile.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering why sql server will continue after the error in list 1. Now it seems makes sense. Thank you.